# Using `import type` statement to fix circular dependency reference error

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have two files, A.js and B.js. Both need references to each other like this.

*A.js*

```
import { B } from "b"

export class A {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}

let b = new B();
b.print(new A("This is a random name"));
```

*B.js*

```
import { A } from "a"

export class B {
  print(a: A) {
    console.log(a.name);
  }
}
```

The example above will create a circular reference which currently does not work in the JavaScript runtime I'm using. The file *B.js* really only need the type information, not the actual export object). I want the type from *A.js* to get static type checking. Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you just move `class A` to a different file, and import them both when you want to do `b.print(...)`?

Comment: or better yet, just make an interface for B that's placed in a different file and have both of the other files use that.

Comment: That's the very definition of a circular dependency. You just need to break that dependency... There's no reason why `A` needs to reference `B`. Move the rest of the code elsewhere.

Comment: use types if you are using typescript

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**NOTE**: This answer is outdated. The "import elision" feature described here was **removed** in [TypeScript 4.9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#javascript-emit-no-longer-elides-imports). Other, newer answers show better ways of doing type-only imports like `import type {A} from 'a'` or `type A = import('a').A`

<del>You don't need to do anything special to import only type information from module `a`.</del>

<del>Typescript will do it for you - if the only thing module `b` needs form `a` is type information, compiled file `b.js` will not have `require("./a")` statement, that is, it will not have runtime dependency on `a`. Quote from [typescript handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios):</del>

<del>> The compiler detects whether each module is used in the emitted</del> 

 <del>> JavaScript. If a module identifier is only ever used as part of a type</del> 

 <del>> annotations and never as an expression, then no require call is</del> 

 <del>> emitted for that module.</del>

<del>Most likely, the example code you posted in your question is incomplete, and real `b` module has runtime dependency on `a` - find out where it is and get rid of that, and you won't have this problem.</del>

Comment: Great answer! I have completely missed this, thanks for letting me know! You are correct in that my example was too simplified for my "real" problem.

Comment: What if the "type only" import has some side effects? Will the require statement be dropped? If so, how does TS determine this?

Comment: I don't think the compiler can determine if something has side effects or not. If a module has side effects, it's better to be explicit and use [import for side-effects only](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only) form of import syntax, alongside with any named or default imports from the same module if there are any.

Comment: Odd I wonder if this changed, because I am seeing typescript emitting a js require which is never read right now.

Answer (score 30):

This is now directly possible in TypeScript 2.9.

```
type MyType = import('mymodule').MyType;
const myValue: import('mymodule').MyType;
```

Comment: This was perfect, thank you very much. I ended up doing `mutation: keyof typeof import('./mutations'),`

Answer (score 14):

As of TypeScript 3.8, use `import type`:

```
import type { SomeThing } from "./some-module.js";

export type { SomeThing };
```

Reference:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-exports

Answer (score -3):

You used the [typescript] tag here, so I am going to assume you are using typescript.

Make this a 1-way street. Kill off the circular dependency. I would probably move this into 1 file, but you can still split it up like this.

**a.ts** (just an interface)

```
export interface A {
    name: string;
    new (name: string);
}
```

**b.ts** (implementation)

```
import { A } from 'a';

export class B implements A {
    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: I can surely move classes to other files (or do other refactoring) to fix the problem but that was not the question in this case.