# What are the real use cases of type-only imports that justify the added verbosity?

Tags: typescript, lint, type-only-import-export

When I upgraded to the latest version of TypeScript and found out about type-only imports, I thought it was super cool and started using it everywhere.

After a while setting up type-only imports, I soon realised I was getting quite more verbosity and "dirty code" I had expected.

Without type-only imports:

```
import { SomeType, someFunction, SomeClassToInstantiate } from '@my-app/lib1';
import { OtherType, otherFunction, OtherClassToInstantiate } from '@my-app/lib2';
```

With type-only imports:

```
import type { SomeType } from '@my-app/lib1';
import { someFunction, SomeClassToInstantiate } from '@my-app/lib1';
import type { OtherType } from '@my-app/lib2';
import { otherFunction, OtherClassToInstantiate } from '@my-app/lib2';
```

Basically, a lot of my imports get duplicated, and it's difficult to track whether I am importing everything in the correct way (the compiler flags if I am importing as type something that I am physically using in the file - but the opposite doesn't hold, I didn't find any tool to flag that an import is only used as type and should be switched to type-only import).

Maybe I am noticing this problem more because I am using NX and a lot of my app's code comes from the libs' barrel files; i.e. it often happens that *both* a type and a non-type have to be imported from the same module.

So I was wondering, what *actual* advantages do I get from using type-only imports everywhere like that? Are there instead specific circumstances in which it's definitely helpful to use it, and it can be bypassed in all the other cases?

If the answer to my previous question is that it should always used when possible, do you know any linting rule to enforce type imports when they can be used?

I don't like the confusion of having nearly double the imports than before, without even knowing that they are consistently split across regular / type-only imports everywhere.

Comment: In example above there's no reason to split the imports. They are useful when you import **only** types from a module and Babel (for example) is used for transpilation, re-export of a type should be removed, but the compiler can’t tell that the re-export is only a type during single-file transpilation

Comment: _This feature is something most users may never have to think about_ More in docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export and PR https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35200

Comment: @AlekseyL. thanks, it looks like I was too eager to use the latest features, without inquiring whether they are actually needed. I understand now that there is no reason to split the imports, and I strongly suspect I don't need import type at all. 

Do you happen to have a link to an article that explains in detail at least one use case in which type-only imports are needed? The typescript documentation you linked mentions Babel for instance, but it doesn't say explicitly what the problem is

Comment: I found two links in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412000/do-i-need-to-use-the-import-type-feature-of-typescript-3-8-if-all-of-my-import

Answer (score 15):

> Are there instead specific circumstances in which it's definitely helpful to use it, and it can be bypassed in all the other cases?

Although it does not hurt to use type-only imports unconditionally (for consistency's sake), there are, indeed, specific circumstances where they are required. The following table compares different option combinations in terms of use cases:

| `isolatedModules`/`preserveValueImports` | `true` | `false` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `true` | Type-only imports are required as single-file processing lacks full type system information to elide type imports. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/NV4eBW) | Type-only exports are required if exporting types. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/wRG1QN) |
| `false` | Preferencial, type-only imports will be elided | Preferencial, type-only imports will be elided |

The most common use case for them is when both `isolatedModules` and `preserveValueImports` are enabled, which is [explicitly documented](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#preserveValueImports):

> When combined with isolatedModules: imported types must be marked as type-only because compilers that process single files at a time have no way of knowing whether imports are values that appear unused, or a type that must be removed in order to avoid a runtime crash.

Another use case is when `isolatedModules` module is enabled (regardless of the `preserveValueImports` option), and you are exporting types (imported or not), which is also [documented](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exports-of-non-value-identifiers):

> Single-file transpilers don’t know whether someType produces a value or not, so it’s an error to export a name that only refers to a type.

If your config has `preserveValueImports` enabled, type-only imports are also useful to force the elision of imports that are only used in type positions that would not be a runtime error if preserved (in the following example, `import type` will allow the compiler to elide the import entirely):

```js
import { ESLint } from "eslint"; // ESLint is a class
let esl: ESLint;
export { esl };
```

---

As for linting, `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` for ESLint has 2 rules that govern the usage of type-only imports and exports:

- [`consistent-type-imports`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/consistent-type-imports)
- [`consistent-type-exports`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/consistent-type-exports)

---

On an off-note, since 4.5, TypeScript has [type modifiers on import names](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#type-modifiers-on-import-names) that were added specifically to address the verbosity of type-only imports, so you no longer need to split imports:

```js
import { someFunction, SomeClassToInstantiate, type SomeType } from '@my-app/lib1';
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning `import { type SomeType, someFunction, SomeClass }` typescript syntax for importing less verbosely.

Comment: @tinystone NP :) Thankfully, the TS team listened to requests and added this option in 4.5 - it was, indeed, quite verbose to have to write the module specifier twice just to be able to use type-only imports.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished my *fun* reading all related issues/proposals/PRs. This is a kindly summary for lazy readers:

1. The type-only imports/exports is a feature proposed to solve a specific problem/trouble. It's not just for fun or providing convenient: TypeScript used to have trouble to satisfy both *camps*:

camp1: please DON'T help me remove *you-guess*-unused imports, because I want **side-effects**:

```
// input
import { OnlyUsedAsType } from "sideEffectMod";
import { UsedAsValue } from "basicMod";

declare const a: OnlyUsedAsType;
const b = UsedAsValue;

// output                       <---- oh no, `sideEffectMod` is removed!
import { UsedAsValue } from "";
const b = UsedAsValue;
```

camp2: please DO help me remove *you-guess*-used imports, because I'm non-typecheck transpiler on `isolatedModules`:

```
import { SomeType } from "someModule"; // <---- oh no, I have to assume it is not a type
export { SomeType };                   // <---- too.
let x: SomeType | undefined;

export { SomeOtherType } from "someModule"; // <---- too.
```

2. So, they decided to create 1) a new syntax -- type-only imports/exports, i.e. `import type {...}` and 2) an option to `preserve` side-effects, i.e. `importsNotUsedAsValues`.

So, happy ending, as both camps were satisfied, right...? Nope. But for the sake of beginner-friendly, let's end it here :)