# Is is a mistake to use type keyword after curly braces in TS when importing constants and files fro one file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, import

I have usages of imports in my project, such as this

```
import { type MyType, MY_CONSTANT } from './index';
```

and it compiles and works pretty well. But this usage is strange for me, and in some computers on local environment it throws syntax error.

I wanted to know if this usage is okay, and from which TS version it became actual?

Comment: It's correct and I've never had any problem with it yet. however, my new prettier config (which is from `create-t3-app`) puts the type in an additional import statement. So I will have 2 import statements. one for types and one for variables: `import type {...} from "..."; import {...} from "...";`

Comment: Well, I added a config on my eslint config file to add type keyword on type imports, and it does not separate the imports and does everything exactly like in my example.

Comment: I checked my code and it uses this plugin: https://github.com/IanVS/prettier-plugin-sort-imports?tab=readme-ov-file#4-group-type-imports-separately-from-values And here is how it is configured in `create-t3-turbo` template: https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-turbo/blob/main/tooling/prettier/index.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to use the "import type" feature of TypeScript 3.8 if all of my imports are from my own file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412000/do-i-need-to-use-the-import-type-feature-of-typescript-3-8-if-all-of-my-import)